# Golang create multireader of bytes.Buffer array

Tags: arrays, io, go

I need Create MultiReader of slice `[]*bytes.Buffer`
`buffer_slice := ... (type []*bytes.Buffer)`
When i write `io.MultiReader(buffer_slice)`

I get the error:
`cannot use buffer_slice (type []*bytes.Buffer) as type io.Reader in argument to io.MultiReader: []*bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method).`

But function signature `MultiReader(readers ...Reader) Reader`

I understand that the transmit array is meaningless, the actual question: besides the trivial cycle, there are no more options?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. The types are different, but the reasons are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your slice should be type `[]io.Reader`

```
b1 := &bytes.Buffer{}
b2 := &bytes.Buffer{}
buffers := []io.Reader{b1, b2}

multi := io.MultiReader(buffers...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, now everything is fine!